# module not found even though I don't use it anymore

Tags: reactjs, npm

`Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './components/AppFooter' in 'C:\Users\TITAS\Desktop\Present Connection\projektas\react-ui-crud\src'`

Sorry for weird question.

To begin with, I deleted AppHeader.js class (the top part of project's website). No problem arised with that. After that, I deleted AppFooter.js too (bottom part) and now it shows me this error. It seems like some part of my code still searches for AppFooter class but I can't find out.

Comment: Some code in your project is still referencing `AppFooter`. You will need to find where that reference is and remove it.

Comment: Some file in this directory is trying to import/access AppFooter that is deleted . That is why this error occurs